# Python 3 Flask Rest Api: "request.get_json()" gives TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Tags: flask-sqlalchemy, flask-restful

I am creating a route in python flask which will server as rest api to register a user.
when I try to get json data passed through postman in POST method, I get error **TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable**

my request from postman:
http://127.0.0.1:5000/register

raw input: {"username":"alok","password":"1234"}

my route and function:

```
@app.route('/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def signup_user():
    data = request.get_json()
    return data['username']
```

As per my knowledge above function should return : "**alok**"

but i get error: **TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable**

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I spending few hours over internet I got answer from flask official website

I had not set mimetype while making request.
If the mimetype does not indicate JSON (application/json, see is_json()), this returns None.

**request.get_json() is used to Parse data as JSON.**
actual syntax is `get_json(force=False, silent=False, cache=True)`

Parameters
**force** – Ignore the mimetype and always try to parse JSON.

**silent** – Silence parsing errors and return None instead.

**cache** – Store the parsed JSON to return for subsequent calls.

So finally I have changed my code to

```
@app.route('/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def signup_user():
    data = request.get_json(force=True)
    return data['username']
```

It is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Add `Content-Type : application/json` to the header of your Post API request .